# Magento2 site wired on ngix server

Tags: magento2, nginx

I have moved my magento2 website from apache server to ngix server and cleared the cache and recompile but it's not loading files correctly.

website is completely falling apart. Below is the screenshot of my homepage.

see image [image]

**How to resolve this issue ?**

Comment: Please share your link

Comment: check any errors in your browser console. If something is showing up there, then add that error to this question. Now question is too broad

Comment: I have resolved the issue, it was max_time_execution I increased it from 30 to 1800